# PHP MongoDB count int up

Tags: php, mongodb

how can i count an int up?

This count don't work

```
$db->system->update( array('test' => "one"),
  array('$inc' => array("uniqCounter" => +1 ))
);
```

Comment: `+1` and `1` are the same in every sane programming language. And while that adjective is questionable when used in the same sentence as "PHP" while not prefixed with "in", `+1 === 1` does apply for PHP, too.

Comment: it's not sent in "raw form", that's parsed by PHP

Comment: @Sammaye: MongoDB never sees the `+` character. PHP evaluates the `+1` since it's not a string but a number.

Comment: @Sammaye: `+1` is parsed by PHP and converted to the number `1`... "not sure how people don't understand that" - sorry, but I have the right to correct false claims here.

Comment: @Sammaye: Sure, you could have said, "you're right"... And not wrote nonsense stuff like 1++1, then whine about being bombarded. Grow up.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

Note that it will only do the increment on the first matching document, you have to specifiy an [additional argument](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/) if you want to change all document where `test` is `one`.